# How to execute code to continue with quotes in Javascript

Tags: javascript

I'm using a simple script that auto refresh image, the image that being refresh is a live graph which represents traffic, to pull the time and dates i'm using date in PHP. and basically it looks like this.

```
<?php
date_default_timezone_set("America/Los_Angeles");
$lastday = date("Y-m-d-H-i-s",strtotime("-1 days"));
$today = date("Y-m-d-H-i-s");
?>
</style>
<script type='text/javascript'>
      var lastday="<?php echo $lastday; ?>";
      var today="<?php echo $today; ?>";
      document.write(lastday);
window.setInterval(function() {
    var d = new Date();
    $("#myimg").attr("src", "http://192.168.10.35/chart.png?graphid=-1&id=8459&avg=60&sdate=document.write(lastday);&edate=document.write(today);&hide=-4,4&clgid=&width=520&height=215&graphstylefile=graphstyling.htm&animationandinteraction=1&datastylefile=graphdatastyling.htm&animationstylefile=graphanimationstyling.htm&graphstyling=baseFontSize=%2711%27%20showLegend=%270%27%20tooltexts=%271%27&datastyling=drawAnchors=%271%27%20anchorRadius=%271%27%20lineThickness=%272%27&refreshable=true?"+d.getTime());
}, 2000);
</script>
```

now take a look at this line, (12)

$("#myimg").attr("src", "http://192.168.10.35/chart.png?graphid=-1&id=8459&avg=60&sdate=**document.write(lastday)**;&edate=**document.write(today);**&hide=-4,4&clgid=&width=520&height=215&graphstylefile=graphstyling.htm&animationandinteraction=1&datastylefile=graphdatastyling.htm&animationstylefile=graphanimationstyling.htm&graphstyling=baseFontSize=%2711%27%20showLegend=%270%27%20tooltexts=%271%27&datastyling=drawAnchors=%271%27%20anchorRadius=%271%27%20lineThickness=%272%27&refreshable=true?"+d.getTime());

the bold part in the code is the dates in php, the issue is that the code not running since the document.write(lastday); is inside quotes and not show the graph.

using the code like this

```
$("#myimg").attr("src", "http://192.168.10.35/chart.png?graphid=-1&id=8459&avg=60&sdate=" + document.write(lastday); + "&edate=" + document.write(today); + "&hide=-4,4&clgid=&width=520&height=215&graphstylefile=graphstyling.htm&animationandinteraction=1&datastylefile=graphdatastyling.htm&animationstylefile=graphanimationstyling.htm&graphstyling=baseFontSize=%2711%27%20showLegend=%270%27%20tooltexts=%271%27&datastyling=drawAnchors=%271%27%20anchorRadius=%271%27%20lineThickness=%272%27&refreshable=true?"+d.getTime());
```

is not possible since the code will be ended in the first quote.
any ideas how can I make it work?

Thanks!.

Answer (score 0):

First of all whoever gives the negative reputation. Kindly provide the explanation as well since new user won't understand what issue they are doing.
Next the solution for the above issue is you can do the above thing in two way one by using purely Javascript other by using PHP in Javascript.
Solution by using PHP in Javascript

You don't need to use `document.write` since it will print on the same web page and no output will generate. You can directly use the JS variable in your string like following

```
$("#myimg").attr("src", "http://192.168.10.35/chart.png?graphid=-1&id=8459&avg=60&sdate=" + lastday + "&edate=" + today + "&hide=-4,4&clgid=&width=520&height=215&graphstylefile=graphstyling.htm&animationandinteraction=1&datastylefile=graphdatastyling.htm&animationstylefile=graphanimationstyling.htm&graphstyling=baseFontSize=%2711%27%20showLegend=%270%27%20tooltexts=%271%27&datastyling=drawAnchors=%271%27%20anchorRadius=%271%27%20lineThickness=%272%27&refreshable=true?"+d.getTime());
```

Other solution is you can take the date in Javascript only and then do the above thing. Date can be taken by Date function of Javascript.

Comment: extract your remark about downvotes into a comment. It does not belong in an answer.

Comment: First of all, thank you for that, that what i'm thinking, seems like people here think that if you not born with the knowledge to code, you are not belong here.
and regrading the question, I tried what you post, not working yet, I tried also the dates in Javascript, its not working good since javascript date function not working as expected like in PHP.
you have any ideas?

Comment: No its not like that this community is really helpful but the actual issue is community will only help if you have already researched on that topic.
If you go to the topic here on Stack Overflow about when to post question you will find out that user can only post once they have researched thoroughly which unfortunately you didn't able to figure out anyway if you like the answer then you can add 1 reputation Or else can comment here your issue.

Comment: Negative rate to question without explain why is being a pure hater, I researched my question for almost 3 days before post this question here.

Comment: Alright don't bother the solution that i gave worked for you or not.

Comment: already answered for that, no :(
the date format that should be is like this YYYY-MM-DD-HH-MM(minutes)-SS(Seconds)
the issue with date in Javascript is the month and day show one number and it should be for example February 02 and not 2.